# bash - Read input line from file then delete

Tags: bash, shell

I have this bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DOMAINS=( '.com' '.co' )

while read input; do
  for (( i=0;i<${#DOMAINS[@]};i++)); do
  MATCH=$(whois "$input${DOMAINS[$i]}" | grep -oPa '^.*\b(Creation Date)\b.*$')
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "$input${DOMAINS[$i]}\tregistered\t"$(date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S)"\t$MATCH" | tr '\n' '\t' |& tee --append output/registered.txt
    echo "" |& tee --append output/registered.txt
  else
    echo -e "$input${DOMAINS[$i]}\tavailable\t"$(date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S)"\t$MATCH" | tr '\n' '\t' |& tee --append output/available.txt
    echo "" |& tee --append output/available.txt
  fi
  done
done < "$1"
```

input.txt looks like this:

```
domain1
domain2
domain3
```

Which is returning this to the console:

```
$ ./script.sh input.txt
$ domain1.com    registered  Creation date: 15-jan-2015
$ domain1.co     available  Creation date: 15-jan-2015
$ domain2.com     registered  Creation date: 15-jan-2015
$ domain2.co      registered  Creation date: 15-jan-2015
$ domain3.com     registered  Creation date: 15-jan-2015
$ domain3.co      registered  Creation date: 15-jan-2015
```

How to modify this script, to remove the readed lines from input.txt?

Thank You for your help!

**EDIT:**

Here is Cas' solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

DOMAINS='.com .co' # simple, space-separated list of domain suffixes

while read input; do
  for d in $DOMAINS; do
    MATCH=$(whois "$input$d" | grep -oPa '^.*\b(Creation Date)\b.*$')

    if [ $? ] ; then regavail="registered" ; else regavail="available" ; fi

    # what's the `tr` for below? is it really needed?
    # Is $MATCH really going to have more then one line in it?
    out=$(printf '%s\t%s' "$(date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S)" "$MATCH" | tr '\n' '\t')

    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$input$d" "$regavail" "$out" |& tee --append "output/$regavail.txt"

    seen+="$input\|"
  done
done < "$1"
seen=$(printf '%s' "$seen" | sed -e 's/\\|$//')
sed -i -e "/^\($seen\)$/d" "$1"
```

Which is great, but only deleting the lines when the script totally finishes. Is there a way to deleting the lines, when I terminating the script with CTRL+C also?

How I can "trap" (if this is the good term to use here) CTRL+C and send a signal like if the script reached the last line of input.txt? This will delete the already processed lines, or the entire input.txt file, including the unprocessed lines?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a version where it creates an `input-cache.txt` file where real-time removing the used lines. If `input-cache.txt` not present, then `input.txt` stays intact. So, at the first start, when only `input.txt` is presented, it will copy everything from this file into `input-cache.txt`. The script reads from `input.txt`, but the `sed` command constantly, real-time removing those lines from the mirrored `input-cache.txt`. This is when you first time start your script. But what's happening when you halt the script from running with CTRL+C? In this case, everything in `input.txt` will be reversed back to `input-cache.txt`, which is now only will have the unprocessed lines, just like in `input-cache.txt`. One of the drawback is if you give new lines into `input.txt`, it will instantly removed at the next start. PLUS, the files in the script are hardcoded. I just don't know how to call the input file that I specify with the fire up command: `./script.sh files/input.txt`?

Probably there is a better way to create a cache file than re-writing `input.txt` with it when the script restarted.

```
#!/bin/bash

# USAGE
# ./script.sh files/input.txt

cat files/input-cache.txt > files/input.txt
cat files/input.txt > files/input-cache.txt

DOMAINS='.com'

while read -r input; do
  for d in $DOMAINS; do
    MATCH=$(whois "$input$d" | grep -oPa '^.*\b(Creation Date)\b.*$')
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "" |& tee --append files/registered.txt
      echo -e "$input$d\tregistered\t"$(date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S)"\t$MATCH" | tr '\n' '\t' |& tee --append files/registered.txt
    else
      echo "" |& tee --append files/available.txt
      echo -e "$input$d\tavailable\t"$(date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S)"\t$MATCH" | tr '\n' '\t' |& tee --append files/available.txt
    fi
  done
  sed -i "/$input/d" files/input-cache.txt
done < "$1"
```

Comment: what do you mean by "used line"?

Comment: The line that reads from input.txt. So when reading `domain1`, then delete it from input.txt. Basically when it ends that file, it needs to become empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line between the `fi` and the first `done`:

```
seen+="$input\|"
```

Then, after the final `done`, add the following lines:

```
seen=$(printf '%s' "$seen" | sed -e 's/\\|$//')
sed -i -e "/^\($seen\)$/d" "$1"
```

This builds up a regular expression containing all domains already seen and processed in the input file ("$1"), and then deletes them all from that file.

If your version of `sed` doesn't support the `-i` (`--in-place`) option, you can do it with a temporary file instead:

```
tf=$(mktemp)
sed -e "/^\($seen\)$/d" "$1" > "$tf" && mv -f "$tf" "$1" || rm -f "$tf"
```

---

here's a simpler, more readable and maintainable version of your script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

DOMAINS='.com .co' # simple, space-separated list of domain suffixes

while read input; do
  for d in $DOMAINS; do
    MATCH=$(whois "$input$d" | grep -oPa '^.*\b(Creation Date)\b.*$')

    if [ $? ] ; then regavail="registered" ; else regavail="available" ; fi

    # what's the `tr` for below? is it really needed?
    # Is $MATCH really going to have more then one line in it?
    out=$(printf '%s\t%s' "$(date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S)" "$MATCH" | tr '\n' '\t')

    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$input$d" "$regavail" "$out" |& tee --append "output/$regavail.txt"

    seen+="$input\|"
  done
done < "$1"
seen=$(printf '%s' "$seen" | sed -e 's/\\|$//')
sed -i -e "/^\($seen\)$/d" "$1"
```

Comment: of course, just deleting (`rm -f "$1"`)or erasing (`> "$1"`) the file after the final `done` is simpler, unless there's another process appending new domain names to the file while it's being processed.

Comment: in the latter case (where another script is appending new domains), commenting out the "used" domains is probably better than deleting them.  And then modify your script to ignore comments. And modify the append-domains script to check if a domain exists in commented or uncommented form before appending it.

Comment: Sorry, I putted in the example an older version of the script. I updated my question.

Comment: there's nothing in your updated script that requires a change in my answer.  however, your script is grossly over-complicated so i'm going to add a simpler version to my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I getting the following error: `: No such file or directory`

Comment: tr is needed becaue if I specify multiple greps, I don't want the second grep parameter going into a new line.

Comment: where are you getting that message?  is it from the `#!/bin/bash` line?  then change that line to have the correct path to your bash interpreter.  Don't use `#! /usr/bin/env bash` because that's broken in too many ways to list here.  btw, `#!/bin/sh` (or whatever the path to your sh interpreter is) will work with this script too because it doesn't use any bash-specific features.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank You! Also feel a little bit faster!
Looks like the problem was caused by windows line endings in the new file. I always forget to set it to linux...

Comment: Seems like there's one problem with this solution: if I terminate the script with CTRL+C, than it will not deleting the lines. Only if I leave it to finish. The problem is that the input.txt sometimes can have 1.000.000+ lines, so I not always run the script until it's totally finishes. If this will run on a VPS, server restart can also be a problem, because I think that case the script also will be terminated?

Comment: you know, it's quite rude and obnoxious to accept an answer and then unaccept it because you've decided to add yet another completely-unmentioned-until-now thing.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific on the first time. So I restored the answer accept. The script is working in a fashion to immediately writing data in the console and files also. I thought your solution should be work in the same way.

Comment: The whole refactoring is nice for a maintanable code, but the really important part is to achieve a maintanable data flow, which is restart/terminate proof. I needed to ask the question this way: `bash - Read input line from file then delete that line immediately`. My bad.